# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException JSON expression can not be empty

Tags: json, web-services, jakarta-ee, jersey

I know what this exception reports for me. Its a null return. But I want to pass a null object, and want to receive a null object. I dont want to check for null and create a empty object, its a waste of cpu resource, since null conveys what it has to, no data found. How can I allow JSON to send a null.

OR

Am I without options here, I need to create a dummy object and send it over the wire ?

SubscriberListRequest request = new

```
SubscriberListRequest((SubscriberListConcrete)element.getValue()) ;
SubscriberListResponse response ;
clientSession = sessionManager.getClientSession(identityHash) ;
clientSession.getSendQueue().sendRequest(request) ;
try {
    response = (SubscriberListResponse)clientSession.waitAndGetResponse(request) ;
} catch (WaitedLongEnoughException e) {
    return Response.serverError().build() ;
} catch (UnableToResolveResponseException e) {
    return Response.serverError().build() ;
}
//
// Should I check for response.getSubscriberList() == null, create a new SubscriberList() and send it over the wire ?
//
return Response.ok(response.getSubscriberList()).build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really pass `null` over the wire, so I suggest you use the Null Object pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and create a static empty array/list in `SubscriberListResponse` which will be returned from `SubscriberListResponse.getSubscriberList()` in case of no results. Then you don't have to check for null in your service, but in `getSubscriberList` to make sure you always return a valid object.